# Вычисляемая колонка (Generated Column) в mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица products. И там есть столбцы qty (количество), buy_price (цена покупки) и total (итог). Можно ли как то  внутри MYSQL умножить поле qty на buy_price и вытащить ответ в поле total?
Структура таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buy_price` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_price` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `categorie_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `media_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Тестовые данные:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `qty`, `buy_price`, `sale_price`, `categorie_id`, `media_id`, `date`) VALUES
(2, 'Samsung', '10', '500.00', '510.00', 1, 0, '2017-07-31 15:31:48'),
(3, 'LG', '5', '250.00', '260.00', 2, 0, '2017-08-03 12:33:17');
```

Спасибо всем за ответы. Решил этот вопрос весьма банально (может даже и не корректно), сделал UPDATE как и подсказали

```
update products set total=qty*buy_price
```

А для остальных товаров сделал умножение прямо в PHP (не знаю насколько это правильно).

Всё же пришлось сделать через триггер как и подсказал Anatol.

Comment: почему просто так же через PHP не посчитать?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, дело в том что товары уже добавлены они уже есть в базе. Нужно получать "умножение" внутри mysql. Возможно ли вообще такое ? или уже поздно (

Comment: ааа... ну достаточно сделать `update` и всё.  `update table set total=qty*buy_price`

Comment: структура таблицы не такая, как описана в вопросе - это раз, исправьте описание. Где поля *total*, *qty*?

Comment: во-вторых, проблема очевидно с типами, тк. количество текстовое почему-то

Comment: Обычно в БД не принято хранить данные, которые легко вычисляются на ходу из уже имеющихся данных. Т.е. поле total вообще не нужно. при любой выборке можно сразу и перемножить или например создать view в которой будет эта вычисляемая колонка. Если все таки очень хочется - то сделать триггер, который будет поддерживать актуальное значение и выполнить один раз update всей таблицы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать (с пересозданием таблицы) так:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buy_price` decimal(25,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(qty AS UNSIGNED) * buy_price),
  `total` decimal(25,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_price` decimal(25,2) NOT NULL,
  `categorie_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `media_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

С пересозданием колонки так:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN total ddecimal(25,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(qty AS UNSIGNED) * buy_price);
```

Или триггером:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTriggerName
  BEFORE INSERT ON products
  FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.total = CAST(qty AS UNSIGNED) * buy_price;
```

Comment: Спасибо Anatol, первый код почему то выдал ошибку A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SET" at position 34) А второй сейчас попробую

Comment: Попробовал через второй код. В поле total нету значения. А при добавлении другого товара из PHP уже выдает ошибку  Error on this Query :
 INSERT INTO products ( name,quantity,buy_price,sale_price,categorie_id,media_id,date) VALUES ( 'Ball', '2', '100', '120', '2', '0', '2017-08-05 08:47:53') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='Ball'

Comment: поправил первый вариант, проверьте

Comment: вторая ошибка связана с повторяющимся ключом, видимо ограничение в таблице на повторы наименований, проверьте данные

Comment: @AlexStassov -  *Anatol. запрос выдает ошибку* - хорошо, оставьте этот вариант. Второй вариант с триггером 100% рабочий

Comment: Anatol, запрос с триггером прошел без ошибок. Но почему то в поле total все нули стоят...хотя в двух других столбцах данные есть.

Comment: пример данных дайте на которых тестировали

Comment: Давайте я приведу код таблицы в тексте вопроса ?

Comment: да, и набор тестовых данных

Comment: @AlexStassov изменил триггер с учётом предварительного преобразования типа, проверяйте. Не забудьте сперва сделать `DROP` уже существующему триггеру или перепишите через `ALTER`

Comment: Предлагаю сделать такой же триггер на UPDATE. Иначе данные в total не будут пересчитываться при обновлении. И конечно, если на момент когда создаются триггера, записи уже есть, надо сделать один раз update всех строк, для приведения в правильный вид

Comment: @Mike согласен, только сначала надо победить проблему - *почему то в поле total все нули стоят...хотя в двух других столбцах данные есть*

Comment: Работает Anatol спасибо Вам большое за ответы за старания (написали бы в ответ я бы принял) и всем остальным так же огромное спасибо за советы, ответы, предложения !

Comment: @AlexStassov - так это и есть ответ, вы его сейчас и комментируете